# Hive UDF performance too slow

Tags: hive, database-performance

I have executed the Hive SQL script with Custom Hive UDF function in Select query where condition, it has been running more than two days.
I would like to know what exactly the problem here? invoking java takes much time or query execution it self taking much time?

My Data set is as follows,
Table A has 2 million records,
Table B has 1 million records,

The Sample Query is as follows

Select ********
FROM
            (SELECT *
            FROM A A1
            WHERE A1.ds in  ('2014-06-11', '2014-06-12') 
            ) A1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT *
            FROM B B1
            WHERE B1.ds in  ('2014-06-11', '2014-06-12')
            ) B1  Where customUDF(A1.data, B1.data)

What could be the issue here? is there any hive script profiing tool available to find where exactly time has been taken?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have access to the UDF, you can add the following to the function (sudo code):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
MapredContext context = MapredContext.get();
Reporter reporter = context.getReporter();
String group = "instrumentation.udf";
String counter = "customUDF";

// function business logic

long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
reporter.incrCounter(group, counter, elapsed);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
There is no such class called MapredContext :(

Comment: Any update? Can any one help us to solve the performance issue?